# Adicionar um short-code para executar codigo de JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, plugin-wordpress

Eu estou a fazer um plugin simples que faça um código curto para executar um código javascript que mostra a pesquisa do Google atraves de um shortcode, mas parece que me escapou alguma coisa no meu código.
Pois Não Consigo Visualizar Nada

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: google search shortcode
Version: 1.0
Description: google search shortcode [mediaads_google]
Plugin URI: https://mediaads.eu/
Author: Helder Ventura
Author URI: https://mediaads.eu
Version: (standalone)
Usage: install activate and done
*/




function show_google_function( $atts ) {



    echo'<script type='text/javascript' src='http://m.free-codes.org/g.php?id=2002'></script>';
    echo'<center>';
    echo'<FORM method=GET action="http://www.google.com/search">';
    echo'<TABLE bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><tr><td>';
    echo'<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">';
    echo'<IMG SRC="http://www.google.com/logos/Logo_40wht.gif" <br></A>';
    echo'<INPUT TYPE=text name=q size=31 maxlength=255 value="">';
    echo'<INPUT TYPE=hidden name=hl value="en">';
    echo'<INPUT type=submit name=btnG VALUE="Google Search">';
    echo'</td></tr></TABLE>';
    echo'</FORM>';
    echo'</center>';


}


add_shortcode( 'mediaads_google', 'show_google_function' );

?>
```

Comment: Aqui é em português. Por favor, traduza a pergunta.

Comment: Faltou traduzir o título.

Comment: Uma observação, precisa escapar as aspas: `<script type=\'text/javascript\'...`

Comment: Ou trocar para aspas duplas: `<script type="text/javascript"...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa escapar os caracteres de aspas simples, ou convertê-los em aspas duplas.

```
echo'<script type='text/javascript' src='http://m.free-codes.org/g.php?id=2002'></script>';
```

deveria ser:

```
echo"<script type='text/javascript' src='http://m.free-codes.org/g.php?id=2002'></script>";
```

ou:

```
echo'<script type=\'text/javascript\' src=\'http://m.free-codes.org/g.php?id=2002\'></script>';
```

---

Quando estamos tratando de Strings, precisamos nos atentar a caracteres especiais — especialmente quando estes são utilizados pela linguagem.

Basicamente, quando estamos dando um `echo` em algum valor, precisamos escapar ou substituir caracteres especiais. O caractere de escape é o `\` (contra barra).

Seu uso é simples, como pode ver nos exemplos abaixo:

## Imprimindo na tela utilizando a função echo com aspas duplas:

```
echo "Meu professor uma vez disse: \"Escape sempre caracteres especiais!\"";
```

resulta em:

> Meu professor uma vez disse: "Escape sempre caracteres especiais!"

O mesmo resultado seria obtido utilizando echo com aspas simples:

```
echo 'Meu professor uma vez disse: "escape sempre caracteres especiais!"';
```

Note que não foi preciso escapar as aspas duplas, pois a string não interfere na função.

---

## Dúvidas comuns

> Então devo sempre utilizar a função `echo` com aspas simples para não
>   precisar escapar os caracteres?

Não. Em certos momentos — como no caso da função do **AP** — você precisa utilizar as *single quotes* (aspas simples), então terá que realizar o escape das mesmas.

Você pode ver mais [neste link oficial](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) do PHP.

> Qual a diferença entre o echo com aspas simples e aspas duplas?

Quando se utiliza aspas duplas para montar uma string, você ganha alumas vantagens.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

//Imprime o nome do usuário na tela
   $nome = "Daniel";

//Utilizando aspas duplas
   echo "Olá, {$nome}!";

//Utilizando aspas simples
   echo 'Olá, '.$nome.'!';
```

Note como no caso das apas duplas foi possível isolar a variável nome dentro da própria string, não necessariamente tendo que concatenar a mesma.

Mais detalhes [neste stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) (em inglês).

Lembrando que em ambos os casos você ainda assim precisa escapar os caracteres especiais.